# How can I identify the graph of a function and the graphs of its first derivative and second derivative?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

[image: This is the image for the question:]

Identify the graphs $A$ (blue), $B$( red) and $C$ (green) as the graphs of a function and its derivatives:

1. _____ is the graph of the function
2. _____ is the graph of the function's first derivative
3. _____is the graph of the function's second derivative

Comment: When a function reaches a local minimum or maximum its derivative cancels, thus you can identify which function is which.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a list to follow;

1. Check local minimum and maximum. These are going to be zero values in the first derivative since their tangent is parallel to x axis.
2. Check if the graph's slope is increasing or decreasing in a specific point. If increasing the derivative will be in positive side of the y-axis.
3. Look at the sign changes of the first derivative in order to find zero's of the second derivative.

Following the list, the answer will be;
f(x)=A
f'(x)=B
f''(x)=C

Answer (score 0):

1.) A

2.) B

3.) C

The red graph is zero when the blue graph reaches it's local extrema, and the green graph is zero when the red graph reaches it's local extrema. As the other similar relations do not hold the result follows.

**Edit:** Notice that the blue graph is similar to the graph of $\frac{sin^2(x)}{x^2}$.

Answer (score 0):

the function has the blue graph.

the first  derivative is zero when the function reaches an extremum, its graph is the red one.

the second derivative gives information on curvature. It is positive when the function decreases and increases just after.
it is negative when the function increases and then decreases.
its graph is the green one.

Answer (score 0):

Find where one is always increasing, and the other always corresponds to be positive, and find where the function is decreasing, to find the corresponding negative function.  The graph that's positive and negative while the other is increasing and decreasing is a derivative function.  The graph that is increasing and decreasing would be the antiderivative function.